# negative numbers passed to view functions are treated differently to negative numbers passed to transaction functions

Tags: solidity, testing, integers, view

Using solidity 0.4.18 I have the following contract:

```
contract MyContact {

    mapping(address => uint) private balances;

    modifier positiveNumber(uint number) {
        require(number > 0);
        _;
    }

    function deposit(uint amount)
      external
      positiveNumber(amount)
    {
      balances[msg.sender] += amount;
    }

    function hasFunds(address depositor, uint amount)
        external
        view
        positiveNumber(amount)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return balances[depositor] >= amount;
    }
}
```

I have the following tests (trimmed for relevance)

```
it('punter can\'t deposit negative amount', async () => {
  await assertThrows(myContract.deposit(-1, { from: punter }))
})

it('negative amount fails', async () => {
  await assertThrows(myContract.hasFunds(punter, -1))
})
```

The first test passes.

The second test fails.

If I try a test like

```
it('zero amount fails', async () => {
  await assertThrows(myContract.hasFunds(punter, 0))
})
```

That test passes.

It seems that with a `view` style function the `-1` is not actually being seen as a negative number.

Is there something special about `view` functions that would cause this to happen, or am I scapegoating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I worked this out.  The `u` in `uint` is 'unsigned' (duh) so when javascript sends in `-1` Solidity sees it as `1.157920892373162e+77`.

In my actual code I had an additional modifier that checked that the amount deposited was actually approved (depositing ERC20 tokens) and that's why the test was working.

Nothing like coding solidity to make one feel like an utter noob.

Comment: What did you do then? Did you just remove the tests involving checking for a negative number?

Comment: @Thanh-QuyNguyen yes